# How do I use a variable from my MainActivity in my layout?

Tags: java, android

I have a method that I want to use to display in the layout itself

```
public void GetPacificTime() 
{
    java.util.TimeZone pt = java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8");
    java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(pt);
    System.out.println(c.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
}
```

How would I use this in my layout XML?

Comment: You can't use System.out.println in layout.xml I guess !

Comment: Please add more info. about what do you want to do?

Comment: I want this method to output (time date etc.) in a box next to some text that I would put most likely put directly on the layout.xml

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a TextView in your layout XML, then use findViewById() to get this TextView, then attach text on it using the setText() method.

Example:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_from_xml);
text.setText(c.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(java.util.Calendar.SECOND));
```